# Gmaps.js \ Creating a new marker depending where user is located

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using gmaps.js for google maps API. The goal is to create map with user geo location and create new marker. Something like "Hi! You are here!"

The map and geo location works fine, but creating new marker with current user coordinates become an issue for me.

This is the code:

```
// public/core.js
//Creating map
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){
      map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoomControl : true,
        zoomControlOpt: {
            style : 'SMALL',
            position: 'TOP_LEFT'
        },
        panControl : false,
        streetViewControl : false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false
      });

// Define user location
      GMaps.geolocate({
          success: function(position) {
            map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert('Geolocation failed: '+error.message);
          },
          not_supported: function() {
            alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
          }
      });

// Creating marker of user location
      map.addMarker({
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
          title: 'Lima',
          click: function(e) {
            alert('You clicked in this marker');
          },
          infoWindow: {
              content: '<p>You are here!</p>'
            }
    });

});
```

Comment: You say *The map and geo location works fine, but creating new marker with current user coordinates become an issue for me* — but what *is* the issue? Does the code produce an error? Does the function not execute? Is the marker misplaced?

Comment: marker doesn't appears at all

Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined core.js:36
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `map.addMarker` *assumes* that the function above, `GMaps.geolocate`, has succeeded, when in fact `position` will only be set once `success` function resolves:

```
// public/core.js
//Creating map
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){
      map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoomControl : true,
        zoomControlOpt: {
            style : 'SMALL',
            position: 'TOP_LEFT'
        },
        panControl : false,
        streetViewControl : false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false
      });

// Define user location
      GMaps.geolocate({
          success: function(position) {
            map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);


        // Creating marker of user location
              map.addMarker({
                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                  lng: position.coords.longitude,
                  title: 'Lima',
                  click: function(e) {
                    alert('You clicked in this marker');
                  },
                  infoWindow: {
                      content: '<p>You are here!</p>'
                    }
            });
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert('Geolocation failed: '+error.message);
          },
          not_supported: function() {
            alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
          }
      });

});
```